# Dihedral group permutation notation and order

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can anyone explain how to interpret permutations on vertices column in the following [table](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Dihedral_group:D8#Elements) and also what does the order of the element mean?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have a square and you call the vertices $1,2,3,4$. The permutation shows where does the element move each vertex. For example, a rotation by angle $\frac{\pi}{2}$ moves vertex $1$ to the place where vertex $2$ was before the rotation, $2$ moves to $3$, $3$ to $4$ and $4$ to $1$. So the permutation which we used on the vertices is $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)$.

As for the order of elements, in each group $G$ with identity $e$ the order of an element $g\in G$ is defined by $\min\{n\in\mathbb{N}: g^n=e\}$. If there is no $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $g^n=e$ (this might happen only in infinite groups) we say the order of $g$ is $\infty$.

Comment: I am not familiar with this notation for permutations. Can you provide a reference?

Comment: $(a_1\ a_2\ a_3...a_r)$ means that $a_1$ moves to $a_2$, $a_2$ to $a_3$,...,$a_r$ to $a_1$. This is the best way to write permutations. This is the best way to write permutations. You can read here: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Cycle_decomposition_for_permutations

Comment: Also check out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation

Answer (score 0):

The 'permutations on vertices column' tells you what the transformation does to each vertex. For example (13) means "1 goes to 3 and 3 goes to 1", (134) means "1 goes to 3, 3 goes to 4 and 4 goes to 1".

The 'order' means how many times you need to do a transformation before all the vertices are back in the initial position. For the two examples I have given above, the orders are respectively 2 and 3.